# jQuery UI Sortable - add item to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to create connected lists using jQuery UI 1.11.4 Sortable and Bootstrap. According to the idea, panels from these lists can easily be moved from one list to another.

To initialize function I am using this simple code:

```
$(function() {
$( ".list" ).sortable({
revert: true,
connectWith: ".list",
handle: ".panel-heading",
tolerance: "pointer",
scrollSpeed: 5
});
```

Also, I am applying CSS options for my lists:

```
.list {
min-height:50px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

I want jQuery to join panel to the list when the pointer is just over it, not only when it is within 40px from the bottom. The solution shouldn't affect page height (as is currently done) to prevent unwelcome appearance of scrollbar.

Any ideas on how to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the scrollbar using this property :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I am not just want to hide the scrollbar, I wish the scrollbar to appear when it's necessary rather when I have a few panels in the list.